# Serializing Arrays in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

Is there a way to Serialize an entire array in C# such as:

```
[Serializable()]
public class Data
{
    public short Some_Short_Data = new short[100,100];
    public string Some_String_Data = new string[100,100];
}
```

Then writting the file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

Data Write_Data = new Data();

XmlSerializer Writer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Data));

    using (FileStream file = File.OpenWrite("Myfile.xml"))
    {
        Writer.Serialize(file, Write_Data); //Writes data to the file
    }
```

When I try this, it fails on: 
     XmlSerializer Writer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Data));

Saying: "There was an error reflecting type 'Data' "

I am particularly new to both Stack and Xml/Xml Serialization so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Data` may be not unique because it may be defined in multiple used namespaces. Please show your `using` statements in the code.

Comment: My code is exaclty as is in my program. Changing the arrays to a single string and short it works fine and will write the data to file - *Edit* Misread, will add in.

Comment: Multi-dimensional arrays are not supported by xmlserializer.

Comment: Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal `[][]` and `[,]` are completely two different things.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal - I forgot to add those in...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multi-dimensional arrays are not supported by XmlSerialzier. But you can make a workaround by using a temp class something like this

```
public class Array100<T>
{
    public T[] Data = new T[100];
}

public class Data
{
    public Array100<short>[] Some_Short_Data = new Array100<short>[100];
    public Array100<string>[] Some_String_Data = new Array100<string>[100];
}
```

BTW: No need for `Serializable` attribute. It is not used by XmlSerialzier

Answer (score 3):

You cannot serialze a int[,] but you can serialize a int[][]. Before serializing your 2D array, just convert it into a jagged array like that :

```
var my2dArray = new int[2,5];
var myJaggedArray = new int [2][];

for(int i = 0 ; i < my2DArray.GetLength(0) ; i ++)
{
    myJaggedArray[i] = new int[my2DArray.GetLength(1)];

    for(int j = 0 ; j < my2DArray.GetLength(1) ; j ++)
        myJaggedArray[i][j] = my2DArray[i,j]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when attempting to serialize a multi-dimensional array that was one of the values in a dictionary of objects. The approach I took was to wrap all of the arrays in a class that is serializable before serialization and then unwrap them all afterwards.

If you don't care what the data looks like then you can serialize the object using the binary formatter, which can serialize anything marked as serializable, and then persist the binary data as a base 64 encoded string.

The wrapper implementation is below.

```
[Serializable]
public class UnserializableValueWrapper: IXmlSerializable
{
    private static readonly BinaryFormatter Formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    public UnserializableValueWrapper([NotNull] object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
        }

        this.Value = value;
    }

    public UnserializableValueWrapper()
    {
    }

    public object Value { get; private set; }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.ReadStartElement();

        var length = int.Parse(reader.GetAttribute("length"));
        reader.ReadStartElement("Data");

        var buffer = new byte[length];
        reader.ReadContentAsBase64(buffer, 0, length);
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
        {
            this.Value = Formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }

        reader.ReadEndElement();
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("Data");

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Formatter.Serialize(stream, this.Value);
            var buffer = stream.ToArray();
            writer.WriteAttributeString("length", buffer.Length.ToString());
            writer.WriteBase64(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```